# swfobject.embedSWF overwriting "id"-param in Ruby on Rails "show"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, swfobject

I'm facing an issue embedding flash content in a Ruby on Rails 3 view for the **show** operation:
By convention when you define a resource in routes.rb and then access a URL like `/<controller>/<id>` the **show** method of the corresponding controller is called with the `<id>` value copied into `params[:id]` so you can use it to retrieve data from you model.
However, when I embed Flash content on such a page using the dynamic embedding via [swfobject.embedswf(swfUrlStr,...)](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.embedSWF%28swfUrlStr,_replaceElemIdStr,_widthStr,_heigh) the *id* parameter is overwritten by it now containing the *swfUrlStr* which is then passed to the controller.

Is there any elegant way to work around this issue?

Any pointers appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out the problem:

The second request was in fact just the GET request to load the SWF file to embed. Since I put in a relative URL it was sent to the same controller:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("Dummy.swf", [...]);
```

Using an absolute path like this

```
swfobject.embedSWF("/videos/Dummy.swf", [...]);
```

does not entail an additional call to the controller.

Thanks for watching, everybody!